# CSS - Expand child to parent's scroll height

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, html

I'm attempting to put a div inside another div where the inner div is "snapped" to the bottom of the parent.  The problems I'm encountering are that I need to be able to apply jQuery draggable to this div to control the height (while always leaving it snapped to the bottom of the parent), and I also need to be able to drag other controls down to make the scroll height of the parent div change.

I have tried using `bottom:0` with `position:absolute` to make this happen, but if the parent begins scrolling, there is space left on the bottom.  It's not really feasible to add other divs to fix this, as it's necessary to maintain the parent-child relationship.

I also would like to avoid Javascript because the page is already running a lot of Javascript and any handlers that I need to attach might cause IE8 to have major performance losses.

I'm not entirely convinced this is possible so what I'm looking for is a solution or some third party confirmation that this can't be done.  Thanks in advance to anybody who can help!

Here's a fiddle with my current code:
http://jsfiddle.net/3RJ2H/2/

Just to clarify, what I'm basically looking for is a "fixed" positioning, but relative to a parent instead of to the window.  (absolute doesn't accomplish this if the parent scrolls)

Comment: What code have you already written? Can you give a fiddle?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Here's what I'm working with: http://jsbin.com/OJAjivEc/2/edit. Could you tell me what exactly you want to happen?

Comment: @cloudcoder2000  I added a basic example of the code I added.  Sorry for the delayed response!

Comment: @cloudcoder2000  I just changed the URL to include the draggable stuff

Comment: What is the purpose of adding the `draggable`- what are you trying to achieve? I'm confused, because you also want it sticking to the bottom.

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 The draggable allows you to change the height (I know this can also be accomplished by resizable)  The bigger issue is that it doesn't stick to the bottom when you scroll.  In my situation, the red divs and the gray div are both elements that can be added to my application, so they all end up with draggable applied to them.

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 Also, the reason I don't want to use resizable is due to a bug: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3423